# Can user's language be auto-detected in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, localization, google-sheets

Is there a way to detect the user's language in a google sheet?

I tried the following in a sidebar but it returned `undefined` although it works in a regular webpage:

```
var language = navigator.userLanguage;
alert(language);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer is quite easy:

```
 Logger.log(Session.getActiveUserLocale());
```